Stopwatch reports 0ms but it does not seem correct
For a given method, that calls out to a database and does a couple of queries, how can the StopWatch return nanosecond execution time here ?
@Aspect
@Component
public class MethodStatisticsLogger {

  @Around("@annotation(project.aop.MethodStatistics)")
  public Object logStats(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
    try {
      stopWatch.start();
      return joinPoint.proceed();
    } finally {
      stopWatch.stop();
      long totalTime = stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis();
      String timeUnit = "ms";
      if (totalTime == 0) {
        totalTime = stopWatch.getTotalTimeNanos();
        timeUnit = "nanos";
      }
      log.trace(
          "{} executed in {} {}",
          joinPoint.getSignature().toShortString(),
          totalTime,
          timeUnit);
      }
  }
}

There is no way the connection to the oracle database + all the queries take less than a millisecond, yet above stopwatch is reporting nanosecond execution time. There is no @Async going on either, all straightforward method executions.

Show us the code you annotated thusly and the log output. Ideally an [mre].

Alright, your comment triggered a bit more investigation and what is happening is that another method higher up the callstack is also targetted by the annotation. And it seems then that you cannot start 2 StopWatches in nested fashion, even though they are separate instances. Is this correct?

I don't know which specific class you are using there, but any sane StopWatch implementation should make instances be independent when used like this.

This is Spring StopWatch, that's why i added the Spring tag.
